# TaskManager-Styled Listbox in C#

Tags: c#, listbox

How would I get a `ListBox` of the type that is in the Processes tab of the Windows Task Manager in C#?

Is there a reference I need to add, a control or something else?

I've been looking around on Google for hours and I can't find anything.

Comment: Just fill a listbox with the running tasks.

Comment: Which version of Windows? The Windows 8 task manager is considerably different.

Comment: You mean a multi columned Listbox? Are you looking to replicate this Tab or just want to have its layout?

Comment: @Derek Yes, a multi columned listbox.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Something like that? Then you want a `ListView` control with the `Display Property` set to `Details`. You can then edit the columns pro grammatically very easily or by means of a collection editor just find the `Columns` property and click the ellipsis button.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To get the running processes and add them to your ListView, you could do something like:

```
foreach (Process process in Process.GetProcesses())
{
    string[] itemArray = {process.ProcessName};
    item = new ListViewItem(itemArray) {BackColor = Color.White};
    yourListView.Items.Add(item);               
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using winforms for the UI, then it's a [ListView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.aspx) control.

Answer (score 0):

Use the ListView Object, below is a real simple example :-

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.Columns.Add("Image Name");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Username");
            listView1.Columns.Add("CPU");
            listView1.Columns.Add("Memory");

            listView1.View = View.Details;

        }
```